# Setting background color on transparent image in Yet-Another-React-Lightbox

Tags: css, reactjs, next.js

I am working with yet another react lightbox in NextJS, and I wanted to set an image background color for a PNG image.

This is how I have my Lightbox component:

```
<Lightbox
       plugins={[Zoom]}
       open={open}
       closeOnBackdropClick={true}
       close={() => setOpen(false)}
       controller={{ closeOnBackdropClick: true }}
       slides={[
              { src: imagePath },
       ]}
       styles={{ container: { backgroundColor: "rgba(0, 0, 0, .8)" } }}
       carousel={{ finite: true }}
       render={{
              buttonPrev: () => null,
              buttonNext: () => null,
              iconZoomIn: () => null,
              iconZoomOut: () => null
       }}
       zoom={{
              maxZoomPixelRatio: 3,
       }}
/>
```

In this case, `styles` changes the color of the whole background, but I want to change just the color of the image background. My idea is to set that `background-color` property in the `yarl__slide_image` (the class of the `img` tag), but I am not that skilled with CSS to do that.

Is there anything I can do to style the lightbox this way? Is there any property in `Lightbox` that I can use to do this? I also tried to change it overriding `slide` inside the `render` property, but it didn't worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the lightbox image background with the following css:

```
<style jsx global>{`
  .yarl__slide_image {
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
  }
`}</style>
```

Here is a minimal working example - https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/stackoverflow-76122862-7s4ygw?file=%2Fpages%2Findex.jsx